# How to append values in ansible variable using conditional statements

Tags: ansible

I am passing a set of values to the ansible play book. Using the value I try to create a string.

For example, I pass arguments: `first_nm`, `last_nm` and `nick_nm` to my playbook via `--extra-vars`. And inside my `role/`:

```
              <task-name>/
                         vars/main.yml
```

I tried to do the following:

```
full_name: {{first_nm}}  {{last_nm}}{{'-'+nick_nm if nick_nm is defined else ''}}
```

My Problem:

Since `nick_nm` is optional, when its empty or not defined if get the full name as for example : `david john-` with a `-` appended to the value.

So how can I avoid this append. Is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: Did you try your solution? It works for me. No '-' is appended.

Answer (score 6):

You should also check if string is not empty. In your setup you only checking if the variable exists, and since it does the condition  evaluates to True and gives you `- + nick_nm`

You can do it like this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    - first_nm: John
    - last_nm: Smith
    - nick_nm:
  tasks:
   - set_fact: full_name="{{first_nm}} {{last_nm}}{% if nick_nm is defined and nick_nm %}-{{nick_nm}}{%endif%}"
   - debug: var=full_name
```